# Username and Password returns NULL or EMPTY

Tags: powershell

I am a script that will create a local user and set the password.

I put some error checking in to make sure that the name and password was not blank. For some reason even if username and password are not blank it still says that it is NULL or Empty when is not null or empty:

```
$Computername = $env:COMPUTERNAME

$ADSIComp = [adsi]"WinNT://$Computername"
$Username = 'TestProx'
$Username = Read-Host -Prompt 'Please enter the New User'
#check that Username is not empty
if([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($destDir)) 
{            
    Write-Host "Username is NULL or EMPTY"            
} 
else 
{
    $NewUser = $ADSIComp.Create('User',$Username)
    #Create password 

    $Password = Read-Host -Prompt "Enter password for $Username" -AsSecureString
    #check that password is not empty
    if([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($destDir)) 
    {            
        Write-Host "password is NULL or EMPTY"            
    } 
    else 
    {    
        $BSTR = [system.runtime.interopservices.marshal]::SecureStringToBSTR($Password)    
        $_password = [system.runtime.interopservices.marshal]::PtrToStringAuto($BSTR)
        #Set password on account     
        $NewUser.SetPassword(($_password))    
        $NewUser.SetInfo()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Within the first `if` statement you have to check for `$username` and within the second for `$password` instead of `$destDir`:

```
$Computername = $env:COMPUTERNAME

$ADSIComp = [adsi]"WinNT://$Computername"
$Username = 'TestProx'
$Username = Read-Host -Prompt 'Please enter the New User'
#check that Username is not empty
if([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($Username)) 
{            
    Write-Host "Username is NULL or EMPTY"            
} 
else 
{
    $NewUser = $ADSIComp.Create('User',$Username)
    #Create password 

    $Password = Read-Host -Prompt "Enter password for $Username" -AsSecureString
    #check that password is not empty
    if([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($Password)) 
    {            
        Write-Host "password is NULL or EMPTY"            
    } 
    else 
    {    
        $BSTR = [system.runtime.interopservices.marshal]::SecureStringToBSTR($Password)    
        $_password = [system.runtime.interopservices.marshal]::PtrToStringAuto($BSTR)
        #Set password on account     
        $NewUser.SetPassword(($_password))    
        $NewUser.SetInfo()
    }
}
```